# iOS JSON parser: what happens if two keys have the same name?

Tags: iphone, ios, json, parsing, restkit

if the server returns:

```
{
    "repositories":
    {
        "xmlns":{...}
        "repository":{...}
        "repository":{...}
    }
}
```

then is it a valid JSON? I tested it in [This JSON Parser](http://json.parser.online.fr/) and it works fine, but I wonder when I use some parser to parse it and get an NSDictionary, then for the key 'repository', how do I get the two repositories?

Thanks!

Comment: json is supposed to follow certain standards...such as key should be unique...  if you are writing the server side also an array is the best way too implement this as "repository":{}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That JSON parser is not good then, the last value will overwrite the first one.  Use [JSONLint](http://jsonlint.com/) instead to validate your JSON, you will see the result.

Comment: Yes, as I said, the final one is kept and the others are discarded.